# How to reset Form values back to original values depending on which button is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a single form which sends emails to people. There are two buttons to do this: New and Reply.

- Pressing New: If you want to compose a new e-mail then the page should use the default input element values already set in the Form. This includes default attributes of those input elements.
- Pressing Reply: If you want to reply to an existing email, then JQuery modifies the values of the subject field and recipient field before submission. It also modifies some hidden field values and adds the attribute of `readonly` to the subject field.

However if someone clicks on Reply and then changes their mind to actually send a New email, I have lost all the default values and attributes for the Form. I can't enter these values in manually because the values come from a database dynamically.

I can't get my head around how to switch between New and Reply on the page. I guess I could reload the page when someone clicks New but is that the only way?

**EDIT:**
I should have mentioned I need to reset the values of Hidden fields as well. When I say "reset" I actually mean go back to their original values.... not clear the `value` attribute.

Comment: Showing and Hiding doesn't work for you?. Add some conde to help you further

Comment: Store the default values in some variables (`subject`, `content`...) when the page loads and fill the form with these variables when someone clicks on `New`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's exactly what the reset method does.

```
$("#myform")[0].reset();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset

You can also get the default value of an input by getting its value attribute or its default value property (assuming you haven't manually changed them, but you should never do that.)

```
var val = $("#theinput").attr("value");
```

and

```
var val = $("#theinput").prop("defaultValue");
```

Comment: Alternatively <input type="reset" value="New" />

Comment: Will this work for resetting hidden fields back to their original values?

Comment: I think I'm going to have to do a page reload. Reset() is making it look like the form has reset, but some attributes are still there such as "readonly" for textfield.

Comment: Yes, reset only resets the values.

Comment: Its clearing the value attribute, not putting it back to original value like a page refresh would.

Comment: No, it's putting it back to the default value that it was when the server returned the input. If javascript later changed the value, that isn't the default, or *"original"* value.

Comment: In that case it doesn't work on hidden fields I tested it. Dont know why.

Comment: You are correct, it seems to be updating the default value when you update the value of a hidden input. http://jsfiddle.net/t3qwC/1/